# Java code with java.util.Scanner gets "[1]+ Stopped" when run with '&' (in background)

Tags: java, linux, shell, input, background

I wrote a program that supports interactive commands. I use `java.util.Scanner` for the input.

This program is also allowed to be run in background and in this case the Scanner is not necessary. So I want to check whether the program is running in the background.

In fact, when I use `nohup java -jar my.jar &`, the Scanner can throw a Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

With this exception, I can know that this program is running in the background. That's not a problem.

But, when I use `java -jar my.jar &`, the program just stopped and shows:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 java -jar my.jar
```

No exception is thrown. It just stopped.

Here is a demo code. You can easily reproduce it.

```java
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("I'm still working!");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }).start();
        System.out.println("Hi~");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String s = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("s = " + s);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("I'm running in the background!");
        }
        System.out.println("Bye~");
    }
}
```

So my question is, how to identify this scenario in java code? How can I prevent it from "stopped"?

Comment: this may be a good read: https://superuser.com/questions/870160/unix-java-process-stops-running-when-moved-to-background

Comment: Thanks @Stultuske ! The solution in this post is also what I'm using currently - add a command line argument "daemon" to wait indefinitely. But is there a way to check automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find a way myself. When `java -jar my.jar &` is used and the "Stopped" messgae is shown, a `SIGTTIN` signal is actually thrown.

So we can register a `sun.misc.SignalHandler` for this signal. Just like this:

```java
public class MySignalHandler implements SignalHandler {
    public static void register() {
        // The returne value (i.e. the default handler) should be
        // ignored or the "Stopped" will still be shown.
        Signal.handle(new Signal("TTIN"), new MySignalHandler());
    }

    private boolean handled;

    private MySignalHandler() {
        handled = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Signal sig) {
        if (!handled) {
            // SIGTTIN may be thrown several times in a row.
            // But we only need to handle it once.
            handled = true;
            System.err.println("SIGTTIN!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the program will print the log and exit (instead of "stop").

But I still haven't found a way to keep the program running instead of having it quit.